# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result_box' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

```
def meaning(word):    #Outside tkinter window
    data=open_files()
    meaning=data[word]
    for each_word in meaning:
        result_box.insert(END,each_word)
    result_box=" " 


print("Result_box initialised")   # Inside tkinter window
result_box=Text(window,height=20,width=50,wrap="word")
result_box.grid(row=7,column=2,rowspan=6,columnspan=6,padx=2,pady=2)
```

Every things working just fine, just when the meaning() is called this Error 
    shows up. Tried every thing like including the function body inside 
    window.loop() to make it local to tkinter windows but it didn't seem to work.

```
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
```

Comment: It is because `result_box` is treated as a local variable inside `meaning()` function due to the line `result_box=" "`.  So `result_box.insert(...)` inside for loop will raise the error. 
Do you want to append a space to `result_box` at the end of `meaning()` function? If yes, you should use `result_box.insert(...)` instead of `result_box=" "`.

Comment: Have you tried passing result_box as parameter?

Comment: @Jordan.. never tried passing an tkinter object as parameter. How is that done?

Comment: `result_box=" " `,What did you want to do?Did you want to delete the text in your ``Text`` widget?

Comment: What do you mean?You pass it like you do with any other parameter. Your function meaning has one parameter, just add one more.

Comment: Got it buddy,it worked.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This happens because result_box is not defined inside the function. If it is a global variable, you can write

```
global result_box
```

inside the function.

Comment: Thats bad practice